# Build failed while opening a react-native project from github

Tags: react-native

I have downloaded react-native project from github. The link is [here](https://github.com/SkinnyPetee/FirebaseAuth)

I did npm install. everything is fine till now.when I run react-native run-ios I get following error

> User defaults from command line:
>       IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/sriram/Desktop/FirebaseAuth-master/ios/build/Auth
>
> note: Using new build system
>   note: Planning build
>   note: Constructing build description
>   Build system information
>   error: /Users/sriram/Desktop/FirebaseAuth-master/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Auth/Pods-Auth.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "Auth" in project "Auth") (in target 'Auth')
>
> Build system information
>   error: /Users/sriram/Desktop/FirebaseAuth-master/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Auth/Pods-Auth.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "Auth" in project "Auth") (in target 'Auth')
>
> Build system information
>   error: /Users/sriram/Desktop/FirebaseAuth-master/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Auth/Pods-Auth.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "Auth" in project "Auth") (in target 'Auth')
>
> Build system information
>   error: /Users/sriram/Desktop/FirebaseAuth-master/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Auth/Pods-Auth.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "Auth" in project "Auth") (in target 'Auth')
>
> Build system information
>   error: /Users/sriram/Desktop/FirebaseAuth-master/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AuthTests/Pods-AuthTests.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "AuthTests" in project "Auth") (in target 'AuthTests')
>
> Build system information
>   error: /Users/sriram/Desktop/FirebaseAuth-master/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AuthTests/Pods-AuthTests.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "AuthTests" in project "Auth") (in target 'AuthTests')
>
> Build system information
>   error: /Users/sriram/Desktop/FirebaseAuth-master/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AuthTests/Pods-AuthTests.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "AuthTests" in project "Auth") (in target 'AuthTests')
>
> Build system information
>   error: /Users/sriram/Desktop/FirebaseAuth-master/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AuthTests/Pods-AuthTests.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "AuthTests" in project "Auth") (in target 'AuthTests')
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **

Later I tried `cd ios && pod install` 
After that I tried `react-native run-ios`,
I get following error:
The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/sriram/Desktop/Auth/ios/build/Auth/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DoubleConversion-dummy.o Target\ Support\ Files/DoubleConversion/DoubleConversion-dummy.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

This is my PodFile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'Auth' do
  # Pods for Auth
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  target 'AuthTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'Auth-tvOS' do
  # Pods for Auth-tvOS

  target 'Auth-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Go into ios folder and do `pod install`

Comment: I tried pod install and now I'm getting following in Metro bundler terminal.
/Users/sriram/Desktop/FirebaseAuth-master/node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command ; exit;
(base) srirams-Mac:~ sriram$ /Users/sriram/Desktop/FirebaseAuth-master/node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command ; exit;

Comment: and also im getting no bundle URL present in simulator

Comment: is this problem because of gitignore file?

Comment: Can you update your post with proper error and also post your `Podfile`.

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: Can you try building using xcode and give proper error?

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps:

1. Open `Auth.xcworkspace`.
2. On the left side, you will find `Pods` folder. Delete it.
   [image]
3. Now in terminal, go into your project dir, cd into ios and do `rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock`.
4. Do `pod install`.

Comment: I did everything you have listed here but the metro bundler is stuck at loading dependency graph and in iphone simulator says that no bundle URL present

Comment: can you please specify what all should be there in .gitignore file , so that I don't go into this problem again

Comment: @sriramhegde is it building now?

Comment: yes its building but at metro bundler it is getting stuck on loading dependency graph

Comment: @sriramhegde Can you push your changes so I can clone and try again?

Comment: I havent changed anything

Comment: the pods file is not being added togithub due to gitignore file, is it working in your mac?

Comment: Let me fork, make the changes and make a pull request. Fine for you? @sriramhegde

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197757/discussion-between-sanyam-jain-and-sriram-hegde).

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me!!!
Delete the Pods folder in IOS folder.
Then go to main project directory and run command:

```
npx pod-install
```

the pods folder will be recreated.